# Kernel Dies When Using Scikit Learn in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I'm using scikit learn to run a simple machine learning program in jupyter notebook.

This is the code that I have:

```
from sklearn import tree
features = [[140, 1], [130, 1], [150, 0], [170, 0]]
labels = [0, 0, 1, 1]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
print(clf.predict([[150, 0]]))
```

When I go to run the program, I get a message stating: `The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.`

How do I fix this because I can't seem to get my program running?

Comment: Have you tried running the code outside jupyter? Maybe, say in Spyder?

Comment: your code is working fine for me.

Comment: Facing the same issue. apparently, the snipette works on python CLI.. some problem with jupytyer ?